# Safe execute bash script in php

Tags: php, bash, shell, sandbox

I'm working on browser shell in php (it use one of build in exec functions or cgi script in perl or python) and I want to allow for limited access to shell to guest users. I have this function to sanitize the user commands:

```
private function validate_command($command) {
    $commands = array('echo', 'cat', 'ls', 'find', 'cd', 'grep');
    $cmd_re = "(" . implode("|", $commands) . ")";
    $re = "/^\s*($cmd_re|xargs\s*$cmd_re)/";
    $separators = "/(\||&&|\|\||;)/";
    $parts = preg_split($separators, $command, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if (preg_match($separators, $part)) {
            $result[] = $part;
        } else if (!preg_match($re, trim($part))) {
            $last = array_pop($commands);
            $message = "guest user can only execute: " .
                     implode(", ", $commands) . " and " . $last;
            throw new Exception($message);
        } else {
            // escapeshellcmd is not use here because it escape quotes
            // and * ? so you can't use find . -name "*.js"
            $result[] = preg_replace('/(\\\\|`|\$\()/', "\\\\$1", $part);
        }
    }
    return implode($result);
}
```

It work for commands like this:

```
find projects/jcubic -name '*.js' | xargs grep jcubic
```

but not allow to execute `find / | xargs rm` or `rm *` and escape `$(` and `` ` ``

is this function safe? Can it be exploited to execute not allowed commands? If it's not safe how can I make it safe? Is it difficult?

**UPDATE** my updated function after @jh1711 comment:

```
private function validate_command($command) {
    $commands = array('echo', 'cat', 'ls', 'find', 'cd', 'grep');
    $cmd_re = "(" . implode("|", $commands) . ")";
    $re = "/^\s*($cmd_re|xargs\s*$cmd_re)/";
    $separators = "/(&&|\|\||\||;)/";
    $parts = preg_split($separators, $command, null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        if (!preg_match($re, trim($part)) && !preg_match($separators, $part)) {
            $message = "guest user can only execute: " .
                     implode(", ", $commands) . " and xargs";
            throw new Exception($message);
        } else if (preg_match('/(>|`|\$\()/', $part)) {
            throw new Exception("guest user can't use redirect to write to files" .
                                " or execute subshell");
        } else {
            $result[] = $part;
        }
    }
    return implode($result);
}
```

is there anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: `validate_command("echo '<?php exec(base64_decode());echo ' > file.php")` or sth like that would be my first thougt

Comment: @jh1711 oh, I forget about redirects, thanks.